# Incorrect date when trying to insert in database using jdbc, SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, simpledateformat, transient

I'm trying to insert "2016-07-24" into the Oracle database using the JDBC, SimpleDateFormat class. In the database it should be saved as  "24-JUL-16", instead it is inserting "24-JUL-24"
which is an incorrect format. Below is my code. Please let me know what should be changed for the SimpleDateFormat.

I suspect if it is because I haven't declared the

```
 public static final SimpleDateFormat transDate = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

as transient.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import com.myjdbc.database.DBConnection;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class DateInserter {
    private static final String PROCEDURE_FOO = "{call P_PROCESS_FOO(?,?,?)}";
    public static transient final SimpleDateFormat transBusinessDate = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd");
    public static final SimpleDateFormat transDate = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd");

    public static void callProcedure() throws SQLException {
        Connection con = null;
        CallableStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet jdbcRs = null;
        try {
            con = DBConnection.getConnection();
            stmt = con.prepareCall(PROCEDURE_FOO);
            stmt.setString("P_TRANS_ID", "A1221");
            stmt.setDate("P_TRANS_BUSNS_DATE", new java.sql.Date(
                    transBusinessDate.parse("2016-07-31").getTime()));
            stmt.setDate("P_TRANS_DT",
                    new java.sql.Date(transDate.parse("2016-07-30").getTime()));
            stmt.execute();
            jdbcRs = (java.sql.ResultSet) stmt.getObject("P_TRANS_DATA");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("JDBC Exception " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `P_PROCESS_FOO` procedure definition, please?

Comment: can not see `"2016-07-24"` in your code

Comment: Sorry it should be "2016-07-24" in the code, I passed someother value. If the value is passed as "2016-07-31", it's inserting 31-JUL-31.

Comment: does not look like it is the java code's problem.  As per @JorgeCampos how about posting the SP